# Recover free disk space after cloning partition

Tags: partitioning, cloning

I cloned an initial partition which size was 350Gb into a new partition in another disk which size was 450Gb. All went well and everything works fine.

However, when I take a look at file systems in System Monitor, the partition seems to have 350Gb. When I go to Disks, the partition seems to have 450Gb, which is actually the real size.

How can I do to make the system see the additional 100Gb that does not seem to be seeing?

See screenshot here:
[image]